# Confused Procedure or Function Has Too Many Arguments

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, webforms

Ok, first let me apologize for asking what seems like a redundant question. I'm attempting to optimize a stored procedure as well as the code that utilizes it. I've taken all parameters from both the code as well as the stored procedure and put them side-by-side in Excel to get a count of how many were in each. There are 23 in both. There is 1 single output parameter which I think may be causing the issue. I'm not sure how to work with that though if it is.

When I run the code I get the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function spr_SelectClaims has too many arguments specified.

Stored procedure parameters:

```
@BID int = NULL,
@IndID int = NULL,
@RecDateStart datetime = NULL,
@RecDateEnd datetime = NULL,
@ServiceTypeID int = NULL,
@Billed bit = NULL,
@Paid bit = NULL,
@Approved bit = NULL,
@Void bit = 0,
@LocationID int = NULL,
@BillingAgingDate datetime = NULL,
@PaymentAgingDate datetime = NULL,
@ClaimID int = NULL,
@Eligible bit = NULL,
@BillingTypeID int = NULL,
@ClaimDetailID int = NULL,
@SortExpression varchar(25) = NULL,
@ProvidedBy int = NULL,
@Billable varchar(10) = NULL,
@ExpenseOnly varchar(10) = NULL,
@PageIndex INT = NULL,
@PageSize INT = NULL,
@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
```

VB.NET CODE

```vb
Dim helper As New DataBaseHelper(StoredProcedureName)

        Dim _param As SqlParameter() = {
                                           New SqlParameter("@RecordCount",SqlDbType.Int),
                                           New SqlParameter("@BID", IIf(Me.BID Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.BID)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@IndID", IIf(Me.IndID Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.IndID)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@RecDateStart", IIf(Me.RecDate Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.RecDate)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@RecDateEnd", IIf(Me.RecDateEnd Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.RecDateEnd)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@ServiceTypeID", IIf(Me.ServiceTypeID Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.ServiceTypeID)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@Billed", IIf(Me.Billed Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.Billed)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@Paid", IIf(Me.Paid Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.Paid)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@Approved", IIf(Me.Approved Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.Approved)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@Void", IIf(Me.Void Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.Void)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@LocationID", IIf(Me.LocationID Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.LocationID)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@BillingAgingDate", IIf(Me.BillingAgingDate Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.BillingAgingDate)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@PaymentAgingDate", IIf(Me.PaymentAgingDate Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.PaymentAgingDate)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@Eligible", IIf(Me.Eligible Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.Eligible)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@BillingTypeID", IIf(Me.BillingTypeID Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.BillingTypeID)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@ClaimID", IIf(Me.ClaimID Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.ClaimID)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@ClaimDetailID", IIf(Me.ClaimDetailID Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.ClaimDetailID)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@SortExpression", IIf(sortExpresion Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, sortExpresion)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@ProvidedBy", IIf(Me.ProvidedBy Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Me.ProvidedBy)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@Billable", IIf(billableonly Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, billableonly)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@ExpenseOnly", IIf(expenseonly Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, expenseonly)),
                                           New SqlParameter("@PageIndex", Me.PageIndex),
                                           New SqlParameter("@PageSize", Me.PageSize)}
                                           _param(0).Direction =ParameterDirection.Output
        Dim dr As IDataReader = helper.RunDataReader(_param)
```

Excecute Code

```vb
Public Function RunDataReader(ByVal parameters As SqlParameter()) As IDataReader
    Dim dr As IDataReader
    Dim sqlCommand As String = MyBase.StoredProcedureName
    Dim dbCommand As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand)
    dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 160
    If Not (parameters Is Nothing) Then
        For Each param As SqlParameter In parameters
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, param.ParameterName, param.DbType, param.Value)
        Next param
    End If
    'HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(parameters.Length)

    dr = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand)
    Return dr
End Function
```

Comment: You've shown us where you create an array of `SqlParameter` objects. You haven't shown us what you actually do with that array.  For all we know, you add each element 100 times to the command.

Comment: What would help? There is way too much code to place here. After the Dim dr As IDataReader = helper.RunDataReader(_param) There is a While dataReader.Read() called. There error is happening at the Dim dr As IDataReader = helper.RunDataReader(_param)

Comment: By the way, you should not be using `IIf` in this day and age. VB has had an `If` operator for nearly a decade now. You should use it.

Comment: I agree. I inherited this code and slowly trying to optimize it and bring it up to speed. This goes back to the .net 2 days.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?  Is it after that call to `RunDataReader`?  I doubt it, so what use would that code be?  Presumably the exception is thrown when you call `ExecuteReader` on a `SqlCommand`. We would need to see the code that creates and executes that command.

Comment: I've made an edit to the code and now shows you the Execute reader. You are correct. The error is actually thrown during the ExecuteReader. Sorry.

Comment: I would suggest that you place a breakpoint on the `ExecuteReader` line and examine the command object at that point. Based on the information provided, we can only conclude that there are too many parameters on the command for the sproc being invoked OR that that sproc invokes another sproc or database function with too many arguments. We can't really test that from here. But I'd do as described above. Maybe you're not actually executing the sproc you think you are.

Comment: I will try to set a break point there and look at that command to see what exactly is going on. I will advise further.

Comment: It is hitting all 23 parameters. I could post the sproc, however, it's a little large to look at. I think it's like 300 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after doing some additional digging, I found out that for some reason those 23 parameters ended up being 92 parameters. So, the resolution for this would probably be to figure out why the the parameters are trying to be put in 6 times. There is a loop that's happening 6 times, and I know what that loop is Thanks to jmcilhinney suggesting to put a break point at the ExecuteReader. I was able to see a stored procedure being called 6 times.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. You should accept your own answer so that it can be seen that your issue has been resolved without opening the thread. You might need a specific minimum reputation points to do that and I'm not sure what that is, but do it if you can.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to wait until tomorrow before accepting my own answer it said.